# netbeans not executing the given query says error in execution

Tags: netbeans

```
String s1=t1.getText();//book code integer
String s2=t2.getText();//book name varchar
String s3=t3.getText();//student name varchar
String s4=t4.getText();//class varchar
String s5=t5.getText();//roll no varchar
String s6=t6.getText();//issue date varchar
String s7=t7.getText();//return date varchar
String sql="update lib set book_code ='"+s1+"' ,book_name ='"+s2+"' ,student_name='"+s3+"' ,class ='"+s4+"' ,roll_no ='"+s5+"' ,issue_date ='"+s6+"' ,return_date ='"+s7+"'   where book_code ='"+s1+"' ";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.execute();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"the table has been updated");
```

sorry i know its a stupid question but please someone help me with the query section please let me know whats wrong in most probable query section.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic mistake, you are trying to update book_code but at the same time you are using it as a reference number for update statement in where clause. You should use ID or a unique column for these kind of queries which will not be updated/changed.